# ArcGIS Calculate mean NDVI and assign it to polygons attribute table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, attribute-table

I am new to ArcGIS.

I have a group of polygons with attribute tables and I have generated an NDVI map [Edit: by NDVI map i mean a File Geodatabase Raster Dataset with 10980x10980 resolution, 1 band, cell size 10x10, format FGDBR, 32bit, without compression with values from -1 to +1 ] from the whole area. I now need to calculate the mean NDVI value for each region of interest/polygon and then assign the value calculated to the tables accordingly.

How can I do that?

Comment: So you have NDVI as raster cells and want to calculate the mean NDVI from the rasters for a given polygon/area?

Comment: yes GISKid, thats correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Zonal Statistics as Table` tool you can get the mean NDVI value for your polygons (Zones). Select the unique polygon name field as zone field in the tool options. The tool creates its own table and then you can join the mean values to your polygon table by using `Join field` tool and selecting the common polygon name field to  make the join between the two.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer Salman. However i have tried the Zonal Statistics as table tool and it returns an error: "Invalid input geodataset" which is the field i put my NDVI map

Comment: To be more specific, what i did was this:  1)Input raster or feature zone data: The table with the ROIs 2)Zone field: the key value id 3)Input value raster: The NDVI map

Comment: @ODstuck this answer is correct, however you haven't provided enough information  about your "NDVI Map". Please [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/219030/edit) your question to specify the format of the NDVI data (is it a raster? what raster format is it? etc...)

Comment: Thank you
Edit: by NDVI map i mean a File Geodatabase Raster Dataset with 10980x10980 resolution, 1 mand, cell size 10x10, format FGDBR, 32bit, without compression with values from -1 to +1

Comment: What you did seems correct. If you have achieved your result please mark the answer as the correct answer to your question :)

Comment: Thank you once more Salman for the input. Correct i knew it should have been before asking here as i searched before and tried the Zonal statistics as table. However it throws the error i mentioned and this persists without apparent reason. So i guessed for the issue i have to solve maybe this was not the correct methodology. 
Do you maybe have any input on the error i encounter? : 
"ERROR 010088: Invalid input geodataset (Layer, Tin, etc)"

Comment: Damn me! i restarted everything and it worked! I guess this is a lesson to be learned (although we already know it) from this endeavor. When all else fails, or even before all else fails, restart.
Thank you Salman, your input was indeed fine

Comment: Haha indeed restarting ArcGIS is always the final (and often successful) weapon when everything else fails.